Use mail function in php with SMTP
I am trying to send an email to myself but I am getting this error

The code that I use is
function notify_password($username, $password) {
// notify the user that their password has been changed

    $conn = db_connect();
    $result = $conn->query("select email from user
                            where username='".$username."'");
    if (!$result) {
      throw new Exception('Could not find email address.');
    } else if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
      throw new Exception('Could not find email address.');
      // username not in db
    } else {
      $row = $result->fetch_object();
      $email = $row->email;
      $from = "From: di@gmail.com \r\n";
      $mesg = "Your  password has been changed to ".$password."\r\n"
              ."Please change it next time you log in.\r\n";

      if (mail($email, 'login information', $mesg, $from)) {
        return true;
      } else {
        throw new Exception('Could not send email.');
      }
    }
}

I have setup my php.ini file like this

and my sendmail file like this


Note the correct settings for gmail smtp: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en .

P.S. For future reference: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . See also [ask]

mail() is an old low level function, it's close to impossible to get email right by using it. And I don't think it even supports Gmail authentication. Unless you really have spare time to spend on this, you're better off with Symfony Mailer or PHPMailer.
